# Как сделать checked для input используя данную, которая храниться в $_POST

Tags: php, html, input

У меня есть данный HTML

```
 <input id="dt1" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="Other Media" checked>
            <label for="dt1" class="device-type-btn">PC/Mac</label>

            <input id="dt2" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="Hard Disk Drive">
            <label for="dt2" class="device-type-btn">HDD</label>

            <input id="dt3" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="SSD - Solid State Drive">
            <label for="dt3" class="device-type-btn">SSD</label>

            <input id="dt4" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="SD Flash Drive">
            <label for="dt4" class="device-type-btn">Flash</label>

            <input id="dt5" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="SD Flash Drive">
            <label for="dt5" class="device-type-btn">SD</label>

            <input id="dt6" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="RAID Server Drive(s)">
            <label for="dt6" class="device-type-btn">RAID</label>

            <input id="dt7" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="Mobile Phone">
            <label for="dt7" class="device-type-btn">Mobile</label>

            <input id="dt8" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="Other Media">
            <label for="dt8" class="device-type-btn">Other</label>
```

ТАкже, мне приходит данная $_POST, которая хранит в себе `value` значение

Если `value` = Other Media я хочу сделать checked для radio с `value` Other Media, и так для других, все зависит от value
Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: `<input id="dt1" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="Other Media"<?= $_POST['deviceType']== "Other Media" ? ' checked' : '' ?>>`

Answer (score 1):

К примеру так:

```html
<input id="dt1" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="Other Media" checked>
            <label for="dt1" class="device-type-btn">PC/Mac</label>

            <input id="dt2" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="Hard Disk Drive">
            <label for="dt2" class="device-type-btn">HDD</label>

            <input id="dt3" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="SSD - Solid State Drive">
            <label for="dt3" class="device-type-btn">SSD</label>

            <input id="dt4" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="SD Flash Drive">
            <label for="dt4" class="device-type-btn">Flash</label>

            <input id="dt5" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="SD Flash Drive">
            <label for="dt5" class="device-type-btn">SD</label>

            <input id="dt6" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="RAID Server Drive(s)">
            <label for="dt6" class="device-type-btn">RAID</label>

            <input id="dt7" type="radio" name="deviceType" value="Mobile Phone">
            <label for="dt7" class="device-type-btn">Mobile</label>

            <input id="dt8" <?php echo ($_POST['value'] === "Other Media") ? ' checked ' : ''?> type="radio" name="deviceType" value="Other Media">
            <label for="dt8" class="device-type-btn">Other</label>
```